# Is there any performance difference between a value comparison and a value assignment?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jvm, atomic

Consider the following two code examples:

**Example 1.**

```
public void setValue(int value)
{
    mValue = value;
}
```

**Example 2.**

```
public void setValue(int value)
{
    if (mValue != value)
    {
        mValue = value;
    }
}
```

Pretend you've been tasked to optimise some Java code to the absolute max, beyond all common sense.

Would the second code example be an optimisation of the first? By that I mean, is there any difference (no matter how miniscule) between an if condition check and an int assignment at the lowest levels of Java or the JVM?

Comment: "beyond all common sense" - indeed.

Comment: The gains partly depend on how often you assign the same value to `mValue`. If this rarely happens, then the comparison is unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second is likely to be an anti-optimization since on modern processors branching tends to be expensive (primarily because [branch *misprediction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) is extremely costly).

The only way to find out for sure is to profile your code on representative inputs. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for some pointers on how to set up a meaningful micro-benchmark.

Bear in mind that if the code in question doesn't account for a significant fraction of the overall CPU time, all optimizations in the world won't make a lot of difference to the overall performance of your applications.

Comment: If you are very lucky, the conditional branch will be easy to predict, and be no more expensive than a typical operation. If you are unlucky, it will have to flush the pipeline on a significant fraction of the times it is executed.

Comment: The point made by @yshavit below holds for all concurrent access, regardless of the field being volatile. You are trading a branch for a potentially pointless write-miss, which may be a good trade for a given probability of the field changing.

Answer (score 3):

NPE has good advice. One comment I'll add is that probably also depends on whether `mValue` is volatile, and what hardware you're running it on. For volatiles, a write can be several times more expensive than a read. One some hardware (I believe many mobile devices, for instance) a volatile read is pretty far from cheap, so that difference probably goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You could try compiling both and then use a java bytecode disassembler to check the difference. [Wikipedia JVM instruction listings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) might be a good spot to start.

From what I understand of the compilers and VMs I've worked with, the second code snippet will likely be a (minuscule) bit slower due to the extra comparison op.

If your JVM implementation has an optimizer, it will probably be able to reduce your first code sample to a one-op, whereas the second snippet will require at least one or two more ops to account for the comparison op.

Answer (score 0):

Good coding practices says: "delay optimizations before last moment"

But code test says:

- TOTAL(1)=1000000000 1420ms TOTAL(2)=1000000000 2155ms
- TOTAL(1)=1000000000 1374ms TOTAL(2)=1000000000 1884ms
- TOTAL(1)=1000000000 1379ms TOTAL(2)=1000000000 2072ms

**Compare & Set is NOT better.**

```
// Test Code
public class CompareAndSet {
    int mValue;

    // 1
    public void setValue1(int value) {
        mValue = value;
    }

    // 2
    public void setValue2(int value) {
        if (mValue != value) {
            mValue = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int TOTAL = (int) 1e9;
        long ts;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // 1
            {
                ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                CompareAndSet cs = new CompareAndSet();
                for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
                    cs.setValue1(i);
                }
                System.out.println("TOTAL(1)=" + TOTAL + " "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - ts) + "ms");
            }
            // 2
            {
                ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                CompareAndSet cs = new CompareAndSet();
                for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
                    cs.setValue2(i);
                }
                System.out.println("TOTAL(2)=" + TOTAL + " "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - ts) + "ms");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If change "setValueX(i)" to setValueX(1), the times are (compare&set always are NOT better):
- TOTAL(1)=1000000000 1390ms TOTAL(2)=1000000000 1386ms
- TOTAL(1)=1000000000 1354ms TOTAL(2)=1000000000 1353ms
- TOTAL(1)=1000000000 1398ms TOTAL(2)=1000000000 1389ms

Comment: There are several biases in your test, in particular: (i) you don't allow the method to be compiled before measuring results (ii) `mValue != value` is always true => no branch mispredictions.

Comment: Also note that on my machine, I get `TOTAL(1)=1000000000 0ms` because you don't do anything with the results and the whole loop gets optimised away by the compiler...

Comment: test are not perfect, but orientative yes, compare & set is not better... ;-)

Comment: Improperly built tests can actually be misleading (which is orientative, but in the wrong direction)!

Comment: ok, your machine are too machine :-P

Comment: Use JMH to avoid the pitfalls